# Arduino communication to Raspberry Pi using HC-05

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, raspberrypi

I'm using two HC-05 modules on two Arduino UNO boards. One of my modules connected successfully to a raspberry pi port. However the other doesn't want to connect, but sometimes it does and then randomly disconnects. When I did manage to connect both modules to port on the pi I had code written to send data to the pi and display it in the terminal but only one Arduino data would show up on the pi terminal even though both were sending data. Is there an easier way to connect the modules? I've been using the bluetooth manager tool on the pi

```
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(8, INPUT); // first sensor input
 pinMode(7, INPUT); // second sensor input
 pinMode(6, INPUT); // third sensor input
 pinMode(5, INPUT); // fourth sensor input

}

void loop()
{

    int sensordata_1 = digitalRead(8); // read status and store it into variable
     {
          if(sensordata_1 == LOW)        //  CAGE 1
          {
            Serial.println("Arduino 1 s1: 1");  // 
          }
          else
          {
            Serial.println("Arduino 1 s1: 0");
          }
          delay(200);

    }
}
```

```
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(8, INPUT); // first sensor input
 pinMode(7, INPUT); // second sensor input
 pinMode(6, INPUT); // third sensor input
 pinMode(5, INPUT); // fourth sensor input

}

void loop()
{

    int sensordata_1 = digitalRead(8); // read status and store it into variable
     {
          if(sensordata_1 == LOW)        //  CAGE 1
          {
            Serial.println("Arduino 2 s1: 1");  // 
          }
          else
          {
            Serial.println("Arduino 2 s1: 0");
          }
          delay(200);

    }
}
```

```
import serial
import time

port = serial.Serial("/dev/rfcomm2", baudrate=9600)
port_2 = serial.Serial("
port.flush() # This wil flush any input and output buffer, so it will
#avoid receiving or sending bad data

while True:

    if(port.in_waiting > 0):
        data = port.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip() # decode will translate
        #the data from unicode to byte
        print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `port_2 = serial.Serial("` is most likely a copy and paste error on your part, but needs to be fixed if you want 2 serial ports to deal with
2. You only read from `port` in your Python while loop without touching `port_2`. This is the reason you only see output from one serial port
3. You should use a robust serial data packet-system. Right now you have no way of ensuring that the data received in Python is corrupt or not. You can easily use the pip-installable Python package [pySerialTransfer](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/pySerialTransfer) and compatible Arduino library [SerialTransfer.h](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/SerialTransfer) (installable via the Arduino IDE's Libraries Manager).

For theory behind robust serial communication, check out the tutorials [Serial Input Basics](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=396450.0) and [Serial Input Advanced](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=662346.0).